# toggle dynamically created div with dynamic buttons

Tags: jquery

I wanna toggle dynamic divs with dynamic buttons.

here what I have so far.

```
$(document).on('click', '.users', function() {
        let ch = $(this).val(); //gets val of the button which is the id of the divs
        let string = "#" + ch;
        let test = $(string);
        test.toggle();
    });
```

html

```
<div id='user_1'>
//some code
</div>

<div id='user_2'>
//some code
</div>

<div id='user_3'>
//some code
</div>
```

when i click the button that targets the last div it does the work.

but when i click the button which targets the 1st div, it toggles all the div. same with the button to toggle the 2nd div it toggles all the div below the 2nd div.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo where I dynamically add the content you describe, and the `click` event is linked using `.on(...)`.

I've hidden the divs by default by matching any element that has an `id` that starts with `user_`. This is with the CSS `[id^=user_] { display: none };`

See if you can narrow down the `$(document).on(...)` to  an element that isn't as broad, otherwise you might find performance issues. In this example I've linked it to a div with `id` wrapper, so have used `$("#buttons").on(...)`.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
// Dynamically create buttons and divs like you do
let string = "";
let buttons = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  string += '<div id="user_' + i + '">//some code for ' + i + '</div>';
  buttons += '<button class="toggle-btn" value="user_' + i + '">Toggle ' + i + "</button>";
}


// Add buttons and divs to wrappers
$("#buttons").html(buttons);
$("#wrapper").html(string);


// Add clicker event to wrapper
$("#buttons").on("click", ".toggle-btn", function() {

  // Get value from button
  linked_id = $(this).val()

  // Toggle relevant div
  $("#" + linked_id).toggle();

});
```

```css
[id^=user_] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="buttons">
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: still has the same effect. the toggle effect only happens when the div before that has been toggled.

Comment: Sounds like you're nesting you divs, so the subsequent ones will only show if their parents are shown. i.e. `user-2` is inside `user-1` so even when toggled it will remain hidden because  `user-1` hasn't been shown yet.

Comment: what id did to output the div is:

let string = "";

for(let i = 0; i < userdata.length; i++) {
 string += '<div id='userdata[i]'>//some code </div>'
}

then

$('#somewrapper').html(string);

Comment: I've updated my example to dynamically add everything in the same way you do and it works. Have a careful read of your code and compare it to the working example above. Good luck!